# How to get and save REST API data from 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, api, rest, object

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` is the json data link. I want to get, fetch and save those data in database. All the help I've received was about data fetching and showing in Blade templates using the `foreach` method. I did not find any solution about saving that data (I mean full 100 data all together in the database at a time). I can save only one data because the data I am getting from that API link are two dimensional (I mean array inside other indexed-array). Here is controller code given below that I used to save only one data, not the whole as an object or array.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\apipost;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
class postController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
      $response=json_decode(Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
         $apipost=new apipost();
         $apipost->userId=$response[0]->userId;
         $apipost->id=$response[0]->id;
         $apipost->title=$response[0]->title;
         $apipost->body=$response[0]->body;
         $apipost->save();
          return redirect()->to('/');
     }
}
```

Comment: Please add more code like your model, your migration etc

Comment: Thanks stackoverflow and its engineers. I got my right perfect answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your table has the same columns that the response, so you can try this:

```
  public function index()
  {
     $response = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')->json();

     foreach ($response as $post) {
        apipost::create($post);
     }

     return redirect()->to('/')
  }
```

The `->json()` will transform your response in array. You can see the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#making-requests